# Workout specifically for bowling?

Tags: training, bowling

I am an avid bowler, have been bowling in leagues and tournaments for years now.  This year I feel like my strength hasn't been where it needs to be, and sometimes I lose momentum, and start throwing errant shots.  My question is, is there any other avid bowlers out there who have found a combination of exercises, lifting techniques, etc. that help out with bowling?  I know a lot of it is going to do with my legs, since balance is a big part of bowling, and being consistent, but I don't really know what leg exercises I should do in particular.  I'm definitely not in the gym much, so I'm kind of new to the workout scene, and I want to improve my game.

Edit:

I have any type of workout equipment available at any big name Gym facility.

Comment: Is this cricket bowling or ten-pin bowling?

Comment: Ten pin bowling

Comment: Whatever recommendations you receive will be dependent on what type of facilities/equipment you have available if at all.

Comment: I have pretty much anything available to me that I'd need within a workout facility, etc.

Comment: @DannyBland the [tag-wiki](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/bowling/info) should answer your question. [related meta discussion](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/388)

Answer (score 3):

Well the movement in bowling comes specifically from the shoulder, so I would say you have good chances of improving your bowling skills, or at least bowling strength( and strength in general) by doing shoulder press, using dumbells, machines, and plates. Forward arm circles also will work your shoulders out. Forearm strength may also be a factor, which can be attained by chin ups, curls, and dead lifts. As for legs, barbell squats, leg press, and bodyweight squats and lunges will build your quadriceps, which are also a main muscle for bowling and in general.

Answer (score 1):

Just seen this post now as I have been in rehab from a bowling injury. Lots of Yoga for the lower body is excellent as the compression of the SI joint when sliding can lead to sciatica. So quad stretches, hamstring, etc. easy google search for SI joint stretches are great and definitely help with lower back injuries. As for arms, I recommend hammer curls for biceps and while standing up, push a pilates ball against the wall and make the a continual shape of the alphabet to loosen your shoulder. I am surprised by the amount of strength and range I have because of my increase in flexibility.

hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. Can you add any official references on your aswer

Comment: All answers here come from my rehab for the last 18 months of back pain, sciatica, and shoulder pain from physiotherapists, surgeons, and message therapists. Throughout my rehab it has taken me to three different clinics all with similar training and recommendations.